# What does %= in php do

Tags: php

I do not know what `%=` means in PHP I already know that what `.=` means so I m guessing they are very similar. I have searched it p but all it says is what `->` means and I have looked in my book it just says `%=` is an operator.

Comment: That is the `modulo` operator, that deals with remainders, as found in other languages too. See [this reference](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php)

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this a shorthand operator of %.
I mean this full operator: `$a = $a % $b;`
So the shorthand operator: `$a %= $b;`
% is a mod